# Paging Pages - How does it reduce the size of the page table?

Tags: paging

I understand that paging the pages tables does reduce the size of the overall page table, but is this actually solving the problem of reducing space of the pages stored as we also store the actual page tables in memory anyway. So aren't was stored everything we used to store anyway in memory? So how is this reducing space.